# Linking web app to mongoDB in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm new to Docker and I need help setting up my web app.

So I'm able to get my mongo container up and running - it is also the latest version - by running `docker run -d --name mongo1 mongo`.

I then launch the web-app with linking mongoDB by running `docker run -it --link mongo1:mongo --name webapp1 webapp`

It then errors out on the build: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

Here's the build that should be exposing the ports:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /webapp /home/nodejs && \
    groupadd -r nodejs && \
    useradd -r -g nodejs -d /home/nodejs -s /sbin/nologin nodejs && \
    chown -R nodejs:nodejs /home/nodejs

WORKDIR /webapp

COPY package.json typings.json /webapp/

RUN npm install

COPY . /webapp

RUN chown -R nodejs:nodejs /webapp
USER nodejs

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 27017

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: This like may be useful, alongside cml.co's answer: http://www.ifdattic.com/how-to-mongodb-nodejs-docker/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your nodejs app should connect to mongodb using `mongo:27017` (as you set `mongo` as the mongodb alias inside container `--link mongo1:mongo`) and not `localhost:27017` neither`127.0.0.1:27017`.

So, check mongodb connection url.

By the way, exposing port 27017 seems to be not necessary in `webapp` container